# How to apply 'awk' for all files in folder?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am new to awk pls pardon my ignorance. I am using awk to extract tag values from file. following code works for single execution

```
awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{print $2; exit;}' file.txt
```

but I am not sure how I can run it for all files in folder.
File sample is as follows

```
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>XYZ</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
```

Comment: What o/s (windows, linux, mac)?

Comment: Careful with the `exit`. It will really exit and not process any more files after the first time it is executed. Besides your environment we'll probably have to know more about what you're trying to do to be able to give the best help.

Comment: Hi, my os is UNIX (AIX) I am trying to output the tag value and based on that will change another tag such as date from old date to today. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #!/bin/bash

    STRING=ABC
    DATE=$(date +%Y/%m/%d | tr '/' '-')

    changedate(){
    for a in $(ls /root/Working/awk/*)
    do
    for b in $(awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{print $2;}'  "$a")
    do
    if [ "$b" == "$STRING" ]; then
    for c in $(awk -F"<DATE>|</DATE>" '{print $2;}' "$a")
    do
    sed "s/$c/$DATE/g" "$a";
    done
    else
    echo "Strings are not a match";
    fi
    done
    done
    }

changedate
```

When you run it -

```
root@revolt:~# cat /root/Working/awk/*
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>ABC</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>DEF</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>GHI</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>JKL</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
```

## String in code is set to ABC

```
root@revolt:~# ./ANSWER
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>ABC</NAME><DATE>2015-07-24</DATE></BODY>
Strings are not a match
Strings are not a match
Strings are not a match
```

## String in code is set to DEF

```
root@revolt:~# ./ANSWER
Strings are not a match
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>DEF</NAME><DATE>2015-07-24</DATE></BODY>
Strings are not a match
Strings are not a match
```

Alright. So in this you would set the STRING=ABC or whatever your desired string is. You can also set it to = a list of strings you're checking for. 
The date variable echoes the date in the same format (Y/m/d) as your string. The tr command then replaces all instances of forward slashes with hyphens.

First we're creating a function called "changedate". Within this function we're going to nest a few for loops to do different things. The first for loop sets `ls /root/Working/awk/*` to the variable `a`. This means that for each instance of a file/directory in /root/Working/awk/, do the following.
The next for loop is checking for of each instance, grab between the Name tags and print it. Notice we're still using $a as the file because that's going to be the file path for each file. Then we're going to have an if statement to check for your string. If it is true, then do another for loop that will substitute the date in file `a`. If it isn't true, then echo `Strings are not a match`.

Lastly, we call our "changedate" function which basically runs the entire looping sequence above.

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it gets value from first file and stuck.

Comment: Edit: Updated it and wrote it for you. It would help if you explained why it got stuck.

Comment: I tried code with echo on each step after line 1,2,5 & 8 as step 0 to 4 and I get following result, (apologies I am not able to format it correctly in comment section),     STEP 0:  XYZ
    STEP 1:  2015-07-24
    STEP 2:  /home/user/x/A221642390UP00.txt
    STEP 2:  /home/user/x/1221829330UP00.txt

Comment: Can you post your code online somewhere, so we can read it instead of guessing?

Comment: Please find my script at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzJbj8blS1qzejBVcVFEdVRRdUU/view?usp=sharing, Thanks

Comment: Ok, two things, you had a dos line ending file and your final line (Changedate) should be changed to (changedate). Remember, it's calling the function and IS case-sensitive.  Other than that, it worked perfectly fine for me. If you want anything to take effect, remember to uncomment the sed. Also, make sure the string you're searching for is the one specified.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/QYPTBpJK  .  I added a bit more and some nifty tricks to format it. Code above, output pasted below.

Comment: Apologies for late reply (was not well) thnaks for the help I did tweak the code little bit (http://pastebin.com/4fqP2mvW) because the one suggested by you was still getting stuck after first file.

Comment: Here's your problem. STOP putting exit; after the print! You do NOT want it to exit after a positive/negative result.

Answer (score 0):

To answer somewhat generically your question about running awk on multiple
files, imagine we have these files:

```
$ cat file1.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>XYZ</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>

$ cat file2.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>ABC</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>

$ cat file3.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>123</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
```

One thing you can do is simply supply awk with multiple files as with almost any command (like `ls *.txt`):

```
$ awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{print $2}' *.txt
XYZ
ABC
123
```

Awk just reads lines from each file in turn. As mentioned in the comments,
be careful with `exit` because it will stop processing all together after the first match::

```
$ awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{print $2; exit}' *.txt
XYZ
```

However, if for efficiency or some other reason you want to stop
processing in the current file and move on immediately to the next one,
you can use the gawk only `nextfile`:

```
$ # GAWK ONLY!
$ gawk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{print $2; nextfile}' *.txt
XYZ
ABC
123
```

Sometimes the results on multiple files are not useful without knowing
which lines came from which file. For that you can use the built in `FILENAME`
variable:

```
$ awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{print FILENAME, $2}' *.txt
file1.txt XYZ
file2.txt ABC
file3.txt 123
```

Things get trickier when you want to modify the files you are working
on. Imagine you want to convert the name to lower case:

```
$ awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{print tolower($2)}' *.txt
xyz
abc
123
```

With traditional awk, the usual pattern is to save to a temp file and copy
the temp file back to the original (obviously you want to be careful with
this, keeping copies of the orignals!)

```
$ cat file1.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>XYZ</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>

$ awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{ sub($2,tolower($2)); print }' file1.txt > tmp && mv tmp file1.txt

$ cat file1.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>xyz</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
```

To use this style on multiple files, it's probably easier to drop back to
the shell and run awk in a loop on single files:

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>XYZ</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>ABC</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>123</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>

$ for f in file*.txt; do
>   awk -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{ sub($2,tolower($2)); print }' $f > tmp && mv tmp $f
> done

$ cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>xyz</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>abc</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>123</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
```

Finally, with gawk you have the option if in-place editing (much like `sed -i`):

```
$ cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>XYZ</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>ABC</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>123</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>

$ # GAWK ONLY!
$ gawk -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.sav  -i inplace -F"<NAME>|</NAME>" '{ sub($2,tolower($2)); print }' *.txt

$ cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>xyz</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>abc</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>123</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
```

The recommended `INPLACE_SUFFIX` variable tells gawk to make backups of
each file with that extension:

```
$ cat file1.txt.sav file2.txt.sav file3.txt.sav
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>XYZ</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>ABC</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
<HEADER><H1></H1></HEADER><BODY><NAME>123</NAME><DATE>2015-12-11</DATE></BODY>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jas that's rally helpfull but in my case i cannot use gawk.